# I downloaded a PS4 game from a friend's account. If I buy it on my own account, do I need to download it again?

Tags: ps4

I used my friend's PSN account to download and install a game on my own PS4. However, my friend does not want me to mark his account as "primary" on my PS4 so I can play the game while he's online on his own PS4.

I want to buy this game on my own PSN account so I can play it while he's using his own PS4, but I have a poor Internet connection and it would take a long time for me to download the game again. Do I have to download the game again if I play it using a different account?

Comment: I (and probably others) don't understand what your trying to do here. If you buy it, why wouldn't you just download it? Is there an issue with HDD space?

Comment: What i mean is. I did not buy the game previously. I downloaded it from a friend's psn account on my ps. Now the guy does not want to "share" the game and to share the game i have to activate his profile as primary on my ps. At the moment only time i can play is when he is not logged in on his ps. So now the question. Since i already downloaded the digital fifa game itself from his psn on my playstation. Now i want to buy the game digitally again would i be required to download the game again since the digital game is already downloaded???

Comment: If all this is happening on your own PS, then no, you won't have to re download. It's just going to authenticate your DRM to play it. That said, I've never had that specific issue, but something similar.

Comment: Yes.and thank you for your response good lad! My friend bought the digital version on his ps. And i downloaded it from his psn account onto my playstation. So if i understand correctly the whole digital game is already downloaded on my ps. So if i buy it from playstation store it should't download the game again am i right? Haha sorry i just dont want to download it again since it takes forever im from south africa

Comment: @Innus I have rewritten your question to make it clear what you're asking about based on the information from your comments. Comments may be deleted at any time, so it's better to be verbose in the question than terse in the question and verbose in comments.

Comment: Oh, well yes, I believe that's correct. Have fun! Thanks @Nzall, I'm doing this one from my phone!

Answer (score 4):

If you download a game on your PS4, you download the same version of the game no matter what account you use, and the game is downloaded to the system. So if you already have the game downloaded, you can play it using any PSN account that has a license to play the game and don't have to download it again when switching accounts.

Note that it's possible, depending on how you have your PS4 configured, that your progress you made on your friend's account won't carry over to your account. It depends on how the game manages progress and whether the progress is device bound, account bound or both.

Comment: Thank you for your help. My friend bought and dowloaded the game on his psn on his playstation. So i put his psn account on my ps and downloaded it from his. So when i go and buy the game from psn now then i wont be asked to download again? Sorry im not very good with english haha

Comment: @Innus Indeed. Games are installed to a system, not an account. It's when you try to start a downloaded game using a specific account that the check is done whether you may play an installed game.